# Can't insert characters with ^ and ¨ in snap softwares

Tags: keyboard, snap

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10, with a French keyboard (azerty).

On softwares installed with snap, like Slack or Spotify, I can't insert characters with circumflex (^) or diaeresis (¨).

I can insert these signs alone by pressing two times on the key, as usual, but when I press the ^ key and a letter, it doesn't enter anything, while it does on the rest of the system.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with the swiss layout (qwertz) and Ubuntu 18.04. But I'm not sure if it's snap or electron.